# How to run firestore emulator from docker and have data persist

Tags: firebase, docker, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried several things here.  I have run things like https://hub.docker.com/r/mtlynch/firestore-emulator or just the official google sdk image.  The problem is those don't seem to have a way of persisting data.  The firebase tools seem to have this functionality but require that I login.  I would like to run the firestore emulator in docker and have the data persist.  thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to data persist, you will need this command to start Firestore Emulator

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./<dir-name> --export-on-exit
```

Ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2269

For the docker file you mention above, I don't see it support persist data. So my suggestion is to fork it and update the start script then you can persist data by Docker volume

Comment: The problem with this as I understand it is that the docker container then has to have a firebase project initialized which involves logging in and setting up the firebase project either inside the container or mounting a firebase project.  So if I do docker run I have to login to the docker image and run firebase login and init to be able to run emulators:start.  
I don't want to have to link to a project or login.  All I want to do is run the firestore emulator with persist data.

Comment: You don' t need to init any project. All you need to do is to adjust the start script for the docker to Export data on exit, and to import when start

Comment: You can't run firebase emulators:start without running login from firebase from what I can see.  I have a docker file like this:
```FROM node:latest

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install default-jre

    RUN npm install -g firebase-tools

    RUN firebase setup:emulators:firestore

    RUN firebase emulators:start --import=./app --export-on-exit
```

just running that gives an error of:Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)

Comment: It means that you have to run the start command under firebase folder

Comment: That is the core of what I am trying to get at. I dont get a firebase folder in docker without running firebase login and init.  Those require me to actually set up a real firebase project in a docker container.  I don't want to do that since this image will be used by others and I don't want them to have access to my firebase account...